# Could a website run without javascript?

Tags: html

I was wondering if a website can run without JavaScript. I mean only with HTML, CSS, PHP/Django.

Comment: Do you mean **Could a website run without javascript**?. Of course it could. It only depends on what you are trying to achieve with that side

Comment: If u think "if i can make page without JS" it is possible, but if u think "can my browser display web pages without JS" so, he can but almost every page using JS so if u will disable JS in browser other pages will not display correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is optional for the websites, and it can work fine without Javascript.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment rather than as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A website can run 100% without Javascript. Both a static website and a dynamic website.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment rather than as an answer.